# Formatting an SQL PHP script

Tags: php, sql, formatting

I'm in a class, and I've been asked to retrieve information from an SQL table and display it as an invoice. I've got the basics down, however I've now been asked to format the PHP page to look something like this.

[image: PHP page]

I'm a little confused as to how to do this or even where to begin for that matter.

PHP:

```
<?php
require("connect.php");
$inNo = $_POST["inNo"];

$sql = "SELECT invoice.invoice_no, invoice.date, invoice.cust_id, invoice.emp_id, invoice_line.prod_id, invoice_line.qty, product.cost_price, (product.cost_price * invoice_line.qty) FROM invoice INNER JOIN invoice_line ON invoice.invoice_no = invoice_line.invoice_no INNER JOIN product ON invoice_line.prod_id = product.id WHERE cust_id = '" . $inNo . "'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    //open table
    echo '<table class="table table-striped" id="outTable">';
    echo "<tr><th>Invoice no.</th><th>Date</th><th>Customer ID</th><th>Employee ID</th><th>Product ID</th><th>Qty</th><th>Price</th><th>Total cost</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "
        <tr>
        <td>" . $row["invoice_no"]. "</td>
        <td>" . $row["date"]. "</td><td>" . $row["cust_id"]. "</td>
        <td>" . $row["emp_id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["prod_id"]. "</td>
        <td>" . $row["qty"]. "</td><td>" . $row["cost_price"]. "</td>
        <td>" . $row["(product.cost_price * invoice_line.qty)"]. "</td>
        </tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: This question is rather about html/css than about php/sql. Please show us resulting html in a snippet and describe how it differs from what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
require("connect.php");
$inNo = $_POST["inNo"];

$sql = "SELECT invoice.invoice_no, invoice.date, invoice.cust_id, invoice.emp_id, invoice_line.prod_id, invoice_line.qty, product.cost_price, (product.cost_price * invoice_line.qty) FROM invoice INNER JOIN invoice_line ON invoice.invoice_no = invoice_line.invoice_no INNER JOIN product ON invoice_line.prod_id = product.id WHERE cust_id = '" . $inNo . "'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo"<div style='width:50em'>";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $count =0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($count==0){
          echo '<h2 style="text-align: center">Invoice no. " . $row["invoice_no"]. "</h2>';
          echo '<table width=100%>';          
          echo "<tr style='text-align: left'><th>Date</th><th>Customer ID</th><th>Employee ID</th></tr>";
          echo '<td>" . $row["date"]. "</td><td>" . $row["cust_id"]. "</td>
            <td>" . $row["emp_id"]. "</td></table>';
          echo '<table class="table table-striped" id="outTable" width=100% style="text-align: left">';
          echo '<th>Product ID</th><th>Qty</th><th>Price</th></tr>';
        }

        echo "
        <tr>
        <td>" . $row["prod_id"]. "</td>
        <td>" . $row["qty"]. "</td><td>" . $row["cost_price"]. "</td>
        </tr>";
        if ($count==$result->num_rows-1){
          echo '<div style="text-align: right">Total cost: " . $row["(product.cost_price * invoice_line.qty)"]. "</div>';
        }
        $count++;
    }
    echo "</table></div>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```